# I can compile this code and the build is successful, although nothing is printing out on the print line

Tags: java

```
public class TEST { 

    String name1 = "Kelly";
    String name2 = "Christy";
    String name3 = "Johnson";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void displaySalutation(String name1) {
        displayLetter();
    }

    public void displaySalutation(String name2, String name3) {
        displayLetter();
    }

    public void displayLetter() {
        System.out.println("Thank you for your recent order.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to print something?

Comment: if main method is blank, nothing will be printed. as simple

Comment: It shows you are a newbie. You have to call method to make them do their job. So call some method that you have defined in you `main()`.

Comment: Sorry, copied it straight from code runner, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main method needs to make a call to the method containing the print line. This can be done by creating an instance of TEST which contains the methods to print. You then call the methods contained in the instance variable.
I've updated your code to show how to create an instance and call the method.

```
public class TEST {

    String name1 = "Kelly";

    String name2 = "Christy";

    String name3 = "Johnson";

    // Define the entry point
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an instance of test
        TEST test = new TEST();

        /*  Call the displayLetter method within TEST
            Prints "Thank you for your recent order." */
        test.displayLetter();

        /*  Call the printName method with the "Kelly" String as an argument.
            Prints "Kelly" */
        test.printName(name1);
    }

    // Prints a line
    public void displayLetter(){
        System.out.println("Thank you for your recent order.");
    } 

    // Example print variable
    public void printName(String name){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

I've corrected your code so that you can call the displayLetter method but I'm unsure exactly what you would like to do with the other two methods.